# k8s with docker using env variable

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I’ve a docker file which runs inside **side car container on K8S**.
Inside this docker file, I’ve got several binaries (Golang code) that execute on runtime.

In the `dockerfile` I’ve defined `env variable` that I want to access within the binary.

I mean I want to get the value of the `env` from the binary (Golang code), I tried it and it did not work.

Any idea why?

I’m familiar with `configmap` but here I need to check the `env` from the docker which run
on my k8s deployment.

To read the env I use (this code complied to go binary)

```
func main() {

    fmt.Println(“K8SENV:", os.Getenv("K8SENV"))
...
```

inside the docker

```
ENV K8SENV=test123
```

Comment: What did you try? Any code? How did you deploy?

Comment: @BurakSerdar - I deploy just simple code which needs to get env_var value and prints it , ill update my question

Comment: @BurakSerdar - please see my update

Comment: How did you deploy this to k8s? Any env variables specified there?

Comment: [It is neither the code nor docker](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/8c433aabcede61e77dcdfda203d95bd4), but an intricacy of k8s. Belongs to https://serverfault.com hence, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?
You may be losing the ENV variable scope because of multi staged docker image, or maybe something else.

Comment: And whats the output of that code? is it just "K8SENV:"?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulRaheem - yes it doesnt prints the value

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - correct but not sure way k8s blocks it…when you run the docker you see the data but in k8s dont, strange and odd

Comment: Nevertheless, it belongs to https://serverfault.com, since it is a programmer's problem with orchestration software, not a programming problem.

Comment: I replicated it and it worked. Although I was not using multistage builds to create 
the image. The env var created in the container gets propagated within the pod. 
I Tried compiling the go binary locally and at the container run time when deployed. Both worked.

Can you elaborate on this specifically: **"I've a docker file which runs inside side car container in K8s"**. 
Does this mean that you have 2 containers in the same pod?